# Making async call dropboxjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, dropbox-api

I have problem when I want to read directories from the Dropbox API, dropbox.js https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js

The read directories function from the the API looks something like this and I want to assign the value with angular to easily reach it in my HTML.

**UPDATE AFTER HELPFUL QUESTION**

```
client.readdir("/", function(error, entries, stat1, stat2) {
            if (error) {
               return showError(error);
            }

            $scope.dbItems = stat1;
                $scope.$digest();
        });
```

The HTML-code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="dbItem in dbItems">
   <li><input type="image" src="img/folder.png">{{dbItem.name}}</input></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that the Dropbox call takes some milliseconds so I have to reload the page to print the data collected. I've tried some things with both angular and JQuery promises but I can't get i to work. All the examples I find about promises has a setTimeout-function and that is fairly easy to implement but when I try to implement it with Dropbox it doesn't work. Anyone who has tried something similar?

**UPDATE WITH MY PROBLEM**

Now the HTML is updated correctly but I also want to join all of my Dropbox directories to be exported as JSON. I've updated the function above to look like:

```
$scope.listDB = function()
    {   
        client.readdir(dirToString(), function(error, entries, stat1, stat2) {
            if (error) {
                return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
            }

            $scope.dbItems = stat2;
            $scope.$digest();
            testTemp  = stat1._json;
            setFolders(testTemp);
            function setFolders(current)
            {
                for(var i=0,folders = current.contents;i<folders.length;i++)
                {
                    if(folders[i].is_dir)
                    {
                        folders[i].name = folders[i].path.replace(/\/([^)]+)\//,"");
                        folders[i].name = folders[i].name.replace('/',"");
                        $scope.listDBinner(folders[i].name);
                        var inner = $scope.innerItems;
                        folders[i].contents = inner;
                        setFolders(folders[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

With listDBinner:

```
    $scope.listDBinner = function(name)
        {   
            client.readdir(name, function(error, entries, stat1, stat2) {
                if (error) {
                    return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
                }
                $scope.innerItems = stat1;
                $scope.$digest();
                            console.log($scope.innerItems);
            });
            console.log($scope.innerItems);
        };
```

The problem is that the console.log of $scope.innerItems inside of client.readdir is correct and the one outside is just empty. I know this should probably be solved with Promises of some kind but I really can't get it to work.

Comment: first of all, client.readdir callback looks like this function(error, entries) in the doc. did you know what $scope.$digest() for? put it after $scope.dbItems = stat1;

Comment: @wayne client.readdir callback has two optional parameters. $scope.$digest() actually worked for updating the HTML, thanks for that.

Comment: But now I have more problems, I'm updating the question.